# Numpy diag not returning a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to create a vector and embed it on the diagonal of a matrix. I used

```
A = np.random.rand(10, 1)
M = np.diag(A)
```

I thought from [this tutorial](https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/array-creation/diag.php) and others that I should get the elements of A on the diagonal but instead my output is just the first element of A. What is the error here?

Comment: Change the value of `1` to `4` and re-run your code. Only one element because it's taking the diagonal elements

Comment: @bigbounty sorry, my earlier version of the question did not specify n but n= 10. I have a 10x1 vector and I'd now like to get a 10x10 diagonal matrix. Your solution seems to generate a matrix for A but I want to use diag to go from a vector to a diagonal matrix.

Comment: `A` only has one dimension what should its diagonal be? Or put another way, its second dimension contains nothing so you only get the `[0,0]` element.

Comment: @wwii I thought diag worked both ways i.e. from a vector to a matrix and also a matrix to a vector. Maybe this is incorrect? I wanted to take the 10 elements of A (a vector) and write down a 10x10 matrix with these elements on the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanted to take the 10 elements of A (a vector) and write down a 10x10 matrix with these elements on the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere

```
a = np.random.rand(10, 1)

>>> a.ndim
2
```

Returns a 2-d array and [`.diag`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) tries to **extract** the diagonal from it but there is nothing in the *second dimension* so it only returns the `[0,0]` item. To create a 2d array with `a` on its diagonal make `a` a 1-d array.

```
a = np.random.rand(10)
m = np.diag(a)
```